# Emails going to Junk

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

So we are just setting up Marketing Cloud and we started some journeys.  However, all the emails sent from Marketing cloud and the reply as well, go to Junk. Is there a fix to that? So to be more precise, in the Journey we use what we called on behalf sending so it sends an email on behalf of the manager, as soon as someone gets it, once they reply it goes to their junk. PS: it's an Alias because we did put in MC a new domain

Comment: This sounds like an email reputation issue, not necessarily SFMC related. If you believe it is something with your account, your best bet is to talk to SFMC Support as they will be able to work in your account with you to figure it out. Best we can do is guess. E.g. What is your domain/IP reputation? Are you using SAP? DMARC, SPF? is it a validated From name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the replies from your Marketing Cloud emails that are going to junk/spam, then I would work with your team to whitelist the needed RMM [IP addresses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ip_addresses_for_inclusion_on_whitelists.htm&type=5).